# Blender 2.8 subfsurf modifier behave different compare to 2.7

Tags: modifiers, versions

I tried to learn box modeling using Blender 2.8 while using tutorial that was using 2.7 version.

I noticed that the Subsurf modifier doesn't act just like the 2.7 version when i tried to edit my mesh in edit mode.

Is this intended?
Can I somehow changed it so it can act similar just like the 2.7 version?

[image]

Video example on how they behave when I tried to edit them.
https://my.mixtape.moe/ivoyth.webm